# Exchange ActiveSync - how to get latest emails in inbox?

Tags: email, exchange-server, activesync

I have figured out how to get all items in the inbox, but I want to get them in order of newest first. For example I want to get the most recent 999 emails.

I can get the emails from the past 3 weeks (see below FilterType=3) but I want to limit it based on number of emails rather than date.

Here is the XBML command I am calling:

```
<AirSync:Sync>
  <AirSync:Collections>
    <AirSync:Collection>
      <AirSync:SyncKey>
        788321929
      </AirSync:SyncKey>
      <AirSync:CollectionId>
        6
      </AirSync:CollectionId>
      <AirSync:GetChanges/>
      <AirSync:Options>
        <AirSync:FilterType>
          3
        </AirSync:FilterType>
      </AirSync:Options>
    </AirSync:Collection>
  </AirSync:Collections>
</AirSync:Sync>
```